JWT authentication fails
I'm developing a REST service with Spring security, the backend generates the JWT without any problems, I checked all parts of the code, everything seems ok, but when POSTMAN sends a GET request to an endpoint protected by authentication, despite the token is valid,  it receives the STATUS CODE: 403 (forbidden).
I think the issue resides into the security configuration; but I am not receiving any log information useful for debugging...
could anyone suggest a solution?
.... the code
WebSecurityConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration{

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter)  {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }
    
   
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        return security
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers("/signup", "/login", "/hola").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}

SimpleCorsFilter
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter, WebMvcConfigurer   {

    @Value("${app.client.url}")
    private String clientAppUrl = "";

    public SimpleCorsFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String originHeader = request.getHeader("origin");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, observe");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}


Login controller (this class generates the JWT)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginContoller {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final CustomerServiceImpl customerService;
    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    public LoginContoller(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, CustomerServiceImpl customerService, JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect email or password.");
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Customer is not activated");
            return null;
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = customerService.loadUserByUsername(loginRequest.getEmail());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails.getUsername());

        return new LoginResponse(jwt);
    }
}

HelloController (Here there is the endpoint who needs authentication)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(){
        return("Hello from Authorized API request.");
    }
    


}

The JWT generation
The response
It seems allright, but it doesn't work, any suggestion?

Spring security logging
To see debug spring security logs add this to your application.properties:
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

WebSecurityConfiguration
In the configuration class consider use antMatchers instead of requestMatchers (it seems you want to configure calls using only their path, and antMatchers does this).
Moreover add anyRequest().authenticated() to manage all other calls not included in antMatchers.
In the authenticationManager you should insert your customerService and the passwordEncoder.
Here there is your class updated:
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false, securedEnabled = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration{
    
        private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
        private final CustomerServiceImpl customerService;
    
        public WebSecurityConfiguration(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter,  CustomerServiceImpl customerService)  {
            this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
            this.customerService = customerService;
        }
        
       
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
            return security
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.antMatchers("/signup", "/login", "/hola").permitAll())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated())
.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .build();
        }
    
        
        
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http)
                throws Exception {
            return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class).
                    userDetailsService(customerService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).and().build();
        }
    }


your security configuration has no conflict with your intent.
i guess your jwtRequestFilter does not enroll Authentication
to SecurityContextHolder it must have this kind of code
final Authentication token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, userPrincipal.getAuthorities());

final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(token);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

